# Getting Encryption Error while parsing data fetching from Salesforce

Tags: java

> [Error while persisting/updating sales force data in db for :00530000000dXXnAAM]
>   java.lang.Exception: javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException text:
>   "id":"0011300001iidq1AAA","name":"Svebo Sveis  L????ft Svein V Bondal","sic":0
>   message: Input length not multiple of 8 bytes at > com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.finalNoPadding(CipherCore.java:1016)
>   at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:984)
>   at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:824)
>   at com.sun.crypto.provider.DESedeCipher.engineDoFinal(DESedeCipher.java:294)
>   at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2165)

here is code i am using, btw its working in most of the cases but failing for input like above.

```
 for encryption

{

// create a cipher using a key to initialize it
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/NoPadding");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, iv);

// perform the actual encryption
byte[] ciphertext = cipher.doFinal(text);

return ciphertext;
}

   for decryption 
 {
// create a cipher using a key to initialize it
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/NoPadding");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, iv);

// perform the decryption
byte[] decryptedText = cipher.doFinal(text);

return decryptedText;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is quite clear: *Input length not multiple of 8 bytes*.

You have specified `NOPadding`, change that to `PKCS5Padding`.

DES is a block based encryption algorithm, as such the input must be an exact multiple of the block size, 8-bytes for DES. When the input is not *always* an exact multiple padding must be added, the easiest way to to let the implementation do that for you by specifying padding, generally PKCS#5 for DES.

Note 1:
The code has `"DESede/CBC/NOPadding"`, there is a typo, it should be `"DESede/CBC/NoPadding"`, see [Class Cipher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html).

Note 2:
It is best not to use 3DES and it should not be used in new work, instead use the current standard: AES.

Comment: Thanks for quick feedback will try your feedback.